# different answers of scanf of a char with %d and %c

Tags: c, char, scanf, unsigned-char, format-specifiers

This is a program used for swapping the nibbles of a byte, which is perfect for a byte but I faced a problem.

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>  

void main()
{
    unsigned char a = 0;
    scanf("%d", &a);    
    a = ((a << 4) | (a >> 4)); 
    printf("the value of a is %d\n\r", a); 
}
```

You can see in the `scanf` statement that I've received it as `%d` instead of receiving it as `%c` which is for a `char`. The above code works perfectly.  But if I replace `%d` with `%c`, I am getting a different undesired answer

Why?

Comment: Because using the wrong format specifier leads to Undefined Behavior.

Comment: With `scanf("%d", &a)`, you are copying `sizeof(int)` bytes into the memory address of variable `a`. But since `sizeof(a) == 1 < sizeof(int)`, this operation yields memory override, at which point your program's behavior is undefined (i.e., anything could happen).

Answer (score 4):

the correct specifier for `scanf`ing an `unsigned char` is `%hhu`, not `%d`.

So `scanf("%d", &a);` should be `scanf("%hhu", &a);`.

You should also use `int main(void)` instead of `void main()` and remove the `\r` in the printf, because `\n` is a new line on every system.

Answer (score 1):

In your case

```
 scanf("%d", &a)
```

is wrong. `%d` expects a pointer to `int`, not a pointer to `unsigned char`. it will invoke [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The correct way to do it will be

```
 scanf("%c", &a);
```

or

```
scanf("%hhu", &a);
```